# UL LI CSS issue in IE 8

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have the following problem, where an LI item in the list appears to be moved from the rest of the LI items:

[image]

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Any solutions/hacks that worked?

Comment: May we see your markup and styles?

Comment: Also, are you in IE8 standards mode or compatibility view?

Comment: This is a simple list and not a nested list

Comment: The browser in standards mode, but if i change it compatibility view it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the div height, when I increased the div height enclosing the UL it works